# Propagating data with selectAll() of d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a built-in method in d3.js, which would allow me to propagate the data similar to `select(selector)` with `selectAll(selector)`?

If there's no such direct way, please suggest any other tips how to improve the data propagation.

Please read the comments of my example. Here's a [bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/9987916) of it in action.

The example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.chart div {
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 1px;
}
.chart > div {
    background-color: red;
}
.chart > div > div {
    background-color: steelblue;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<div class="chart"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
function draw(data) {
    var divs = d3
        .select(".chart")
        .selectAll(".parent")
        .data(data);
    var enter = divs
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'parent');
    enter
        .append("div")
        .attr('class', 'first');
    enter
        .append("div")
        .attr('class', 'second');

    // Feel free to change the method if you want to test
    var method = 3;
    switch(method) {
    case 1:
        // This works, obviously:
        divs
            .select('.first')
            .text(function(d) { return d.i; });
        divs
            .select('.second')
            .text(function(d) { return d.i; });
        break;

    case 2:
        // This works also, as I create new propagated data:
        divs
            .selectAll('div')
            .data(function(d) {
                var padded = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
                    padded.unshift(d);
                }
                return padded;
            })
            .text(function(d) { return d.i; });
        break;

    case 3:
        // I could do also this:
        divs
            .selectAll('div')
            .call(padData)
            .text(function(d) { return d.i; });
        break;

    default:
        // I'd like to do something similar, built-in into d3.js, which selects all the divs and sets their value without manual the propagation and padding:
        // divs.selectAll('div').text(function(d) { return d.i; });
        break;
    }
}

function padData(divs) {
    return divs.data(function(d) {
        var padded = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
            padded.push(d);
        }
        return padded;
    });
}

var d = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    d.unshift({i:i});
}
draw(d);

window.setInterval(function() {
    var r = Math.random()*100;
    d.unshift({i:r});
    d.pop();
    draw(d);
}, 2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, but `.select()` is the only operator that propagates data to child elements. Using `.selectAll()` in a selection usually means that you want to do something like in the [nested selections tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) and in that case you do need the explicit `.data()` again to tell D3 what parts of your nested data to use.

In many cases, you can probably achieve what you want by modifying the data instead of the way it is propagated. If, for example, you wanted to have a certain number of repeated elements, you would repeat them in your data as well. The idea behind D3 is (as the name suggests) that the visualisation is (almost) entirely driven by the data. That is, if you have complex inheritance and propagation of the data, this should probably be reflected in the data and not just in the code.

Comment: As you said, I have a need for repeated display elements, which are not in the data when I first receive it. I understood I can manipulate the data and duplicate some elements, but I thought I might ask if there's a "d3.js-ish way" to hide the explicit `.data()`. As you suggested, repeating the elements in the data seems to be the "correct" way to do this.